# Star Schema Fact Should not store price - Why?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, star-schema

I cam across this sentence:

> We always strive to make the facts additive across the dimensions and
>   exactly consistent with the grain. Notice that we don’t store the
>   price of the product being scanned *because the price is nonadditive*.
>   Rather, we store the extended price, which can be added freely across
>   products, stores, times and all the other dimensions.

Source:
[Fact Tables - Kimball Site.](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/11/fact-tables/)

I am assuming the Fact is a sales fact table. I understand the difference between additive and non-additive measures.

The item price is additive. This page also thinks it is:
[SQLBI Fact Table Design.](http://sqlserver-qa.net/2015/06/25/different-types-of-facts-and-fact-tables-in-data-warehouse-design/)

I can't understand the justification listed above for why the price is not stored in the fact table. Please explain if you could. Thx.

Comment: In most scenarios the unit price is not additive. In sales data it isn't meaningful to sum up the unit price over time or product line. Possibly there are situations where price is semi-additive but they don't spring easily to mind. Do you have such an example? If so, over what dimensions would you expect to add unit prices?

Comment: The SQLBI Fact Table Design link is almost certainly using the term "SalesPrice" when what they mean is "SalesAmount".  You can see from their example that this is what was intended but the author used the wrong terminology.  If you look at their example of a non-additive fact they use "net profit %".  Net profit is arithmetically derived from unit price and unit cost.  Unit cost is also non-additive.  You can't subtract one non-additive fact from another to get an additive fact.

Comment: @sqlvogel, thanks for your comment. I don't have a real example, but I see your point. How about the Unit Price*Units this combination looks useful. If so, why not have the Unit Price in the fact table? (If you like to move your comment to the answer area I will vote for it).

Comment: @JoelBrown, good point. You are correct Net Profit% is not additive.

Answer (score 2):

Unit price is definitely non-additive. If you want total sales you would add up the extended price (Extended Price = Unit Price x Quantity Sold. For example, if a customer buys 5 packs of gum for $1.00 each, the Extended Price is $5.00). If you summed up the unit prices of each order line for a given date, what would that tell you? Not very useful.

Also notice that the SQLBI reference does not use the term '**Unit**' price.

You could, however, store the Unit Price as a dimension where you may find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please clarify what your refer to as "Extended Price"